# & or + character in document attachment causes page not found

Tags: 7

I have a Drupal 7 implementation with clean urls implemented.  If I attempt to open a file attached to a content page that has an ampersand or a plus in the document name it causes a page not found error and the file will not open.  Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: If you enter the path of the file directly in your browser address bar and replace the `&` with `&amp` does it work then?

Comment: If it's fir the URL you should replace it by `%26`.

Comment: I haven't tried the &amp but the url does work if you put a 25 in front of the amp code (&26), so in the url %20State%20%26%20Local%20 gets changed to %20State%20%25%26%20Local%20.  Great that it works but how do I get cleanurls and/or Drupal to encode the url that way?